# Is it possible to receive sms messages using internet when outside of coverage area of sellular network?

Tags: sms

Is there any way to still deliver sms message to Android/iPhone device in ordinary messages app, when device is outside of coverage area of cellular provider but has access, for example to WiFi internet?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regular SMS message can be sent/delivered only when phone is in radio coverage. However, some applications can show message as SMS following its own protocol over the internet.
Such example is iMessage (Iphones).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done. But it is not an easy.
You need to create an app and install it on the phone. This app should inject SMS into the ordinary message app (I am not completely sure this is possible on iPhone). The app should, using WiFi, get the information about the SMS from somewhere. Different companies like https://twilio.com or https://suresms.com have inbound SMS numbers. So, you send SMS to this "virtual" number, then an app will pickup the message and inject it into the phones ordinary app.
I cannot come up with a solution where the message is delivered to the SIM cards phone number when the sim-card is out of reach.